# Time-lapse software for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, webcam, eee-pc, timelapse, powertoys

Timershot was an excellent part of the [PowerToys for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) collection.  But alas, it doesn't appear to work on Windows 7, even when run in XP SP3 compatibility mode.

Can anyone recommend a good replacement?

(...Preferably one that is compatible with the webcam on an [Eee PC 1005HA](http://commercial.asus.com/product/detail/31).  But I'll take whatever I can get.)

Comment: Which part are you looking for? Camera control (intervalometer) or to string the images together into a video?

Comment: The first one; a program that will just take a photo every few seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some links:

[AvaCam](http://download.cnet.com/RGS-AvaCam/3000-2348_4-10781953.html)

[VideoVelocity](http://www.candylabs.com/videovelocity/)

[Flix](http://www.nimisis.com/projects/flix.php)

The only one I have experience with is AvaCam. It is functional, and works on Vista so it should work on 7.

Comment: Gave AvaCam a try; it works great in Windows 7 (despite the awful interface)!

Comment: Agreed: AvaCam's interface is one that only the author could love. Glad it is working for you.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but it's the first result on Google. I tried AvaCam it worked great, but it would update my clipboard with the most recent frame from my webcam. I got fed up and looked for a different program.

I found an opensource program called [Chronolapse](https://code.google.com/p/chronolapse/) that seems to be working great. It also has the ability to make a video out of a folder of images.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [VideoVelocity Timelapse for Webcam, DSLR and IP Cameras](http://www.candylabs.com/videovelocity).

The software is completely free without limitations for non HD use. It has scheduling, allows you to make a video from a folder of images, screen capture, has always on/reliability functions and the UI is sweet. I'm a bit biased here but definitely give it a try.