# Webcam software for "work area"

Tags: windows-xp, webcam, timelapse

How can I produce a time-lapse video of a workarea (mostly of a project board).

The post [Time-lapse software for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/138960) pointed at some software, but they generate too much video or are images only.

Willing Webcam (http://www.willingsoftware.com/) meets most of what I am looking for, but tends to crash my XP machine (sorry, that's a work restriction).

What I want to do is

- detect motion
- when motion stops, add a frame to a video
- block detection for a time period

Basic time-lapse may be the best solution in the end (and various tools support that) but does end up with a surprising number of people wandering through.

Useful features, but not essential

- add a date and timestamp in the image
- zoom into the portion of the Image I want to keep

Although I would rather a video file were produced, images that could be strung together would do.

Comment: Not going to post as an answer (yet) but take a look at WebCamXP (http://www.webcamxp.com/download.aspx) and see if this is OK.

Comment: Webcam XP seems reliable (probably best menu settings of the many apps I have played with), but unfortunately security mode records the motion - and seems to create new files (the latter may be my fault)

Comment: Alright. Only really used as a webcam server so don't know about the other features that well, but thought it would be worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Have You tried out Vitamin d. http://www.vitamindinc.com

I think it will cover everything you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, although I can set it to monitor people... it records all of the event.  This is another good tool though and the people identification was very good.